# How to filter multiple fields with multiple values using Django/Python?

Tags: python-3.x, django-filter

for loc,deg,dept,key,job_role,insti_loc,insti_name,mark,gen,job_type in
zip(lst2,lst5,lst6,lst1,lst4,lst8,lst9,lst10,lst11,lst12):

```
        if sample.objects.filter(currentcity=loc,job_role_1=job_role,qualification=deg,qualification_dept=dept).exists():
        for i,j,k,l in zip(lst5,lst2,lst6,lst4):
            pro_log=jobseeker_register.objects.filter(Q(currentcity=j) & Q(job_role_1=l) & Q(qualification=i) &  Q(qualification_dept=k))
            for n in pro_log:
                print("now:",n)
                pro_new.append(n)
```

Comment: Hi inr. What is the problem or error you are having with it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.